# Cannot resolved method 'setOnDayClickListener' on CalenderView in Android

Tags: java, android, calendarview

```
mCalendarView.setOnDayClickListener(new OnDayClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDayClick(EventDay eventDay) {
    // Log.e("Event",((MyEventDay) eventDay).getNote()+" <--");
    }
});
```

Getting an error:

```
Cannot resolved method 'setOnDayClickListener(anonymous com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.listeners.OnDayClickListener)'
```

Is there any other way where we can implement the `onDayClick()` method?

Comment: Are you using [this component](https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View)? What's the type of `mCalendarView`?

Comment: are you using third party CalenderView?

Answer (score 1):

May be your problem with implementing wrong class

In your layout `xml`

```
<com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView
android:id="@+id/mCalendarView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your `Activity`

```
com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView mCalendarView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calendarView = (com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.mCalendarView);
...
```

set `setOnDayClickListener` method

```
mCalendarView.setOnDayClickListener(new OnDayClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDayClick(EventDay eventDay) {
     // Log.e("Event",((MyEventDay) eventDay).getNote()+" <--");
  }
});
```

Comment: @SB2019 is this solution solve your problem? If yes then thick the answer, so that user can understand this problem can solved by this answer...